# Check generic subclass in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, subclass, type-constraints

I have the following function in swift:

```
func test<C1,C2>(val1: C1, val2: C2) {
}
```

But I want to use `where` to constraint this function to when `C2` is subclass of `C1`. I tried something like this:

```
func test<C1,C2>(val1: C1, val2: C2) where C2: C1 {
}
```

But it does not work and gives an error as `Type 'C2' constraint to non-protocol, non-class type 'C1'`. Any idea how I should do it?

Comment: Please check this one. I hope it's help you: https://dispatchswift.com/type-constraints-for-generics-in-swift-d6bf2f0dbbb2

Comment: @SagarChauhan sadly my problem is not covered in it. Even though `C: SomeClass` should be available for check if `C` is subclass of `SomeClass`, it seems it does not work if `SomeClass` itself is a generic parameter like my problem.

Comment: i think it is not possible!!

Comment: Why do you need this constraint? What do you want to implement?

Comment: @Qbyte this constraint shows that I can do some operations safely. For example, if the mentioned constraint is valid, I can safely define something like: `var a:C1 = val2` in function

Comment: @Afshin Could you give a more specific example what you want to do? Is it maybe possible to do this with protocols since this function now only works with classes and not with structs and enums?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), @Afshin can you give us some concrete examples of things you want to achieve with this kind of construct? Maybe we can find alternatives to those, since the way you described it it's not possible with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

### What's the problem?

The `:` denotes a [type constraint](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID186):

> Type constraints specify that a type parameter must inherit from a specific class, or conform to a particular protocol or protocol composition.

Unfortunately, this only allows to specify conformance to known classes or protocols, and not conformance to the type of another generic type.

For example:

```
class C {}
func test1<C1,C2:C1>(val1: C1, val2: C2) {  // Not valid C1 is a generic
}
func test2<C1,C2:C>(val1: C1, val2: C2) {   // Valid since C is a known type
}
```

The same applies to `where` clause that further constrain types or associated types.

```
func test3<C1,C2>(val1: C1, val2: C2) where C2:C1 {  // Not valid C1 is a generic
}
func test4<C1,C2>(val1: C1, val2: C2) where C2:C {   // Valid since C is a known type
}
```

The where clause can be about type conformance with `:`  or about having the same type as a known type with `==`.

### Why is there such a limitation

The language design allows you to have specialized implementations when known  types are at play:

```
func test5<C1,C2>(_ val1: C1, _ val2: C2) {   
    print ("general test5")
}
func test5<C1,C2:C>(_ val1: C1, _ val2: C2) {  
    print ("special case of test5") 
}
let p1="Hello world!"
let p2=12
class MyClass:C {}
let p3 = MyClass()
test5(p1,p2)    // ---> general test5
test5(p1,p3)    // ---> special case of test5
```

But the limitations of this feature to known types prevent from defining a specialized implementation in case one type is a subtype from the other.

There is probably a good reason for this.  If conformance to generic types was allowed, there could be more than one suitable specialization possible and the compiler would not have any rule to chose.  Hypothetical example, adding the with a generic conformance to another generic :

```
func test5<C1,C2>(_ val1: C1, _ val2: C2) where C2:C1 {   
    print ("super special case of test5") 
}
```

In this hypothetical example, the compiler would not know which specialization to chose `test5(p1,p3)`.

### Workaround

However, you can implement the function for two types and deal with the special conformance case in the function body:

```
func test<C1,C2>(_ object1: C1, _ object2: C2){
    let concreteType1 = type(of: object1)
    let concreteType2 = type(of: object2)
    if object2 is T {  // check if C2 conforms to C1
        print ("\(concreteType2) conforms to \(concreteType1)")
    }
    else {
        print ("\(concreteType2) is incompatible with \(concreteType1)")
    }
}
```

Note that depending on what you want to do, you may also consider `as?` casting:

```
    if let object3 : C1 = object2 as? C1 {  // check if C2 is castable to C1
        let concreteType3 = type(of: object3)
        print (concreteType1, concreteType2, concreteType3)
    }
```